# How to validate p:pickList to require at least one selection

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have used column picklist to customize columns of table on page and I want to show dialog  message (Atleast one column should be enabled) if user disables all the columns from picklist. That means user should keep atleast one column in enable box.

```
<p:dialog id="pickListDialog" header="Customize View"
                        widgetVar="dlg">
                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <p:pickList id="columnPickList"
                                value="#{Class_Name.columns}" var="col"
                                itemLabel="#{Class_Name.columnPickList.columnsDisplayMap.get(col)}"
                                itemValue="#{col}">
                                <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Disabled</f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="targetCaption">Enabled</f:facet>
                            </p:pickList>

                            <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                                actionListener="#{Class_Name.columnPickList.saveColumns}" onclick="return disableClick();"
                                ajax="false" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:dialog>
```

Javascript method -

```
function disableClick(){   
        if (document.getElementById("form:columnPickList_target").value == ""){
    alert("Please Select Atleast One Field");       
    return false;      
        }
    }
```

Here I have used Javascript for this. But I want to do this by JSF . 
can anyone please tell me ?

Comment: use he required attribute of the pickList. Set it to required="true" and define a requiredMessage.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1 : Using required attribute

```
<p:pickList id="columnPickList" required="true" requiredMessage="Atleast one column should be  enabled"
     value="#{Class_Name.columns}" var="col"
     itemLabel="#{Class_Name.columnPickList.columnsDisplayMap.get(col)}"
     itemValue="#{col}">
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Disabled</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Enabled</f:facet>
 </p:pickList>
```

Case 2 : Opening dialog from backing bean

```
    public void saveColumns()
{
     validateColumns();

    //doSomthing
}

public void validateColumns() {
     //check if picklist target is empty
       if(columns.getTarget().size()==0)
     {
        //open dialog
       message="Atleast one column should be  enabled";
       RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("validationDialog.show()");
     }
}

private String message; //getter and setter
```

dialog :

```
<p:dialog id="valid"  widgetVar="validationDialog">
          <p:outputLabel value="#{yourbean.message}" />
</dialog>
```